# How will I show the data from my database when I view the page based on what is selected in my combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

When I view my sample.php page, I only see my combo box, and when I start to select a value from my combo box, that's when my data from database show which is from my getyear.php.

What I want to do is the moment I view that page with the default value which is, for instance, 2014-2016, I can already see the data from my getyear.php

This is what I have in my javascript:

```
    /* event handler ~ no ajax function shown */
    function showofficers(str){
        if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getyear.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
      if (year =="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
    }
    mlhttp.open("GET","get_year.php?q="+year,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
```

My div is:

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue with:

```
if (year =="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
} else {
    showofficers(year);
};
```

and make sure the function `showofficers` is in context.

Comment: hi sir, sorry this is a late reply, i thought no one will answer, but thank you because you did! i just want to ask what "context" are u referring to?

Comment: The function must NOT be `undefined` in time you call it, so must be in scope, ok? By the way, instead of `if (year =="")` you can also use `if( !year )`.